# Amazon s3 php safely deleting objects

Tags: php, api, class, file-upload, amazon-s3

I'm allowing my users to delete the images that they upload but then can easily delete the images that belong to other users by changing the name of the image.

My working code below for deleting images... User images are fetched using a username prefix e.g. `joe/some_image.jpg` and a user selects which images to delete using check boxes.

```
//images to be deleted
$images = array("joe/angry_robot.jpg", "joe/baby_with_mustache.jpg");

//create multidimensional array to use in class
foreach($images as $key => $value)
{
    $array[] = array(
        'key' => $value
    );
}

$this->load->library('awslib');

//initiate the class
$s3 = new AmazonS3();

$bucket = 'my_bucket';

$response = $s3->delete_objects ($bucket, array(
    'objects' => $array
));

// Success?
var_dump($response->isOK());
```

What solutions are available in S3 for safely deleting objects in buckets? I'm looking for some kind of user authentication method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain a list of the files that each user owns.

```
class User
{
  // yourproperties

  // array of owned images
  private $images;

  public function addImage($image)
  {
      $this->images[] = $image;
  }

  public function ownsImage($image)
  {
      return in_array($image, $this->images);
  }

  public function removeImage($image)
  {
      if( ( $key = array_search($image, $this->images) ) !== false ) { 
          unset($this->images[$key]);
          return true;
      }
      return false;
  }
}
```

Then....
`if( $user->ownsImage($imageToDelete) ) { // proceed } else { // not authorized }`

Map that array to your database in whichever manner you handle persistence.

Or do it any other way within your application. Authorization for end-users shouldn't be handled by S3.

Comment: Thanks I will test that! I'm not sure if you tried this but I noticed in S3 that you can create metadata for objects. Suppose i create a metadata named `username` that is filled with a user's username upon uploading an image. Would I be able to authorize a user by comparing their username with the metadata? This way i dont have to use the database.

Comment: @CyberJunkie You could do that, but calling each item in S3 to get's its metadata will take substantially longer than retrieving a list of items associated with the user from some other form of persisted storage.